# Обработка ошибок, функция

Tags: python

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, у меня есть функция:

```
def bin(n):
if n == 0:
    return []
n, d = divmod(n, 2)
return bin(n) + [d]
```

она возвражает бинарный формат числа(своеобразно), далее:

```
n = input('int:')
if n:
try:
    n = int(n)
except ValueError as err:
    print 'Error n'
else:
  print 'n!'
print bin(n)
```

Мне нужно, когда вводится n, если это объект, который не преобразуется в целое число, то обработать эту ощибку и вывести сообщение, пока ошибка не обрабатывается и я не понимаю почему. И как этот весь код оформить в одну функцию?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать функцию `raw_input()`, вместо `input()`.

PS Попробуйте передать в вашу функцию `bin()` значение `-1` и получите бесконечную рекурсию. И потом я бы сделал проще:

```
# bin() здесь - это встроенная функция python
list(bin(n).split('b', 1)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню там TypeError нужно ловить. 
[Документация](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int).